# C# message: An object reference is required (with Control.Invoke)

Tags: c#, invoke

My code shows the following error message before compiling

> "An object reference is required"

the wrong code is:

```
Control.Invoke(new invokeDelegate(invokeMethod));
```

I put a `static` before `invokeMethod` instance but it doesn't work...
Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication4
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private Thread invokeThread;
        private delegate void invokeDelegate();
        private void StartMethod()
        {
            //Code C
            Control.Invoke(new invokeDelegate(invokeMethod));
            //Code D
        }
        private void invokeMethod()
        {
            //Code E
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Code A
            invokeThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(StartMethod));
            invokeThread.Start();
            //Code B
        }  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling Invoke on the `Control` class itself. You need to call Invoke on an instance of a control.

Have a look at the example code at the bottom of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1hetckb(v=vs.110).aspx, where the code calls `myFormControl1.Invoke`.